# Calculating Casting Method

Tags: methods, casting

I have problem with identifying the correct way to calculate the answer of the following code without Eclipse Java

```
public class testingQ4 {


public static double sum3(double d2,int d3, int d4){
    double x = d2+d3/d4;
    double y = (int) x;
    return y;

}
public static double div2(int d2, int d3){
    double x = d2/d3;
    int y = (int) x;
    return y;

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double d2 = div2(23,2);
    System.out.println();
    d2 = 6.5;
    int d3 = 3;
    int d4 = 2;
    double sum2 = sum3(d2,d4,d3);
    System.out.println("Answer 2 :" +sum2);
}
}
```

I know the answer is `6.0` but why ? I thought the answer was x = `7.0`?

Answer (score 1):

Integer division that results in a fraction is truncated to the lowest full decimal value. When you divide 2 by 3 in your function, your result is 0, added to 6.5, and cast to an `int`. The result is 6 because the fraction is lost.

Answer (score 0):

The division of an int  by another int always results  an int in Java.

For example 3/2 always give 1 and not 1.5 even if you assign the result to a double.

When you assign the result of an integer division to double, first the result is calculated which is an integer and then its casted to double.